# Chinese Remainder Theorem - Simplifying

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have $mp = 156^{107} \pmod{17},\;$ which simplifies to $3^{11} \pmod{17}.$

How did he get the $11$?

Same for

$mq = 156^{107} \pmod {11},\;$ which simplifies to $2^7 \pmod {11}.$

How to get the $7$? I know how to get the $3$ and $2$

Comment: Message, all I remember is using Euler Phi but I can't remember what for

Comment: $107 = 6 \times (\color{red}{17}-1)+\color{blue}{11}$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add that one deduces at once  from *Euler's theorem* that, if $a$ and $m$ are coprime,
$$a^{N}\equiv a^{N\bmod \varphi(m)}\mod m.$$
In particular, if $m$ is prime, $\varphi(m)=m-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) states that: If $a$ and $m$ are coprime then $a^{\varphi(m)} = 1 \pmod{m}$, $\varphi(\cdot)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). So, $3^{16}=1 \pmod{17}$ and $107=16\cdot 9 + 11$.

**Update:** Actually, since $17$ is prime, we could refer to the [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).